# How to enable flink job manager web GUI when REST API is working but not the WEB Interface

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to follow the flink cdc example according to https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-CDC . I have followed it all the way up to the end and can see the data getting to elastic search and kibana can see the index being created. But I cannot get the web ui on the flink job manager to work? I just end up with `localhost didn’t send any data.` . The REST API to the same port works just fine

Any ideas on what may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked it, but for me the Web UI does come up on port 8081. Are you sure you've tried to access http://localhost:8081/ ? If you still can't access it, it's most likely that you have another application already running on that port or your firewall is preventing you from accessing it.

Comment: checked with netstat and the port is open. Confirmed with docker-compose ps as well. And the firewall is disabled. I have Elastic search and kibana running on other containers and their web interface is working fine. Even the REST API for the same port work fine. Just the web UI is not working.